# How to add custom separators in RecyclerView with grid layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I am using `RecyclerView` grid layout. Everything is working fine. I want to add item separator like below image. Any hint how can i achieve this with recyclerview grid? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It is better if you add comment instead of just down voting.

Answer (score 0):

Add it in the recycler view item Layout

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(context,
                GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```